# Putting data from server into a string array

Tags: android, arrays, string

I am getting data from an array from server . Now I want to put the data received (name of the users ) into an string array . I do not know to put data into a string array.

code:-

```
                 JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));
                JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
                    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("please print my name...for....");
                        try {
                                JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                // Pulling items from the array
                                 mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                                }
                                          }
```

Comment: use `arrayName.add(mfname)`

Comment: show your data which is come from server side..

Comment: Do you want to put the data into a String[] array or an ArrayList<String> ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several choices. One being using String[] or ArrayList();

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

     Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

      JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  

       String[] names = new String[jArray.length()];

        for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
         {
              System.out.println("please print my name...for....");
               try {


                        JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         // Pulling items from the array
                         mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
                                 names[i] = mfname;
                                                     }
                                                   }
```

You can use ArrayList() too:

```
List<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
....
names.add(mfname);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like below code:

For Arraylist:

JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

```
JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

 for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
    {
     try {

          JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           String mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
           users.add(mfname);
           }
           catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
```

For String array:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("driver_details");  
String[] users = new String[jArray.length()];

 for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
    {
     try {

          JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           String mfname = jsob.getString("first_name");
           users[i] = mfname;
           }
           catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want array of strings not ArrayList .

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

For **String array**

```
String[] array_items = new String[jArray.length()];
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
      try{
             JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             array_items[i] = jsob.getString("first_name");
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

For **String ArrayList**

```
   ArrayList<String> arraylist_items = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
    {
          try{
                 JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 arraylist_items.add(jsob.getString("first_name"));
             }catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
    }
```